# vk_api. Запуск бота

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, консоль

```
from datetime import datetime, time 
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType 


token = "f2dd6d2eeb8076700f39480c80bcdfed263c0829" 
group_id = "206921980" 
server = "@fro" 
longpool_sleep = "0.5" 


vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = token) 
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, group_id) 
vk = vk_session.get_api() 


version = "release 7.0" 
api_version = "11.9.4"
system = "LongPoll"
language = "Python 3.9.6" 


servertime = str(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%H:%M"))


for event in longpoll.listen():

    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.obj.text.lower() == "test" or event.obj.text.lower() == "тест":
        vk.messages.send(peer_id = event.obj.peer_id, random_id = 0, message = "Tested!")
        vk.messages.send(peer_id = event.obj.peer_id, random_id = 0, message = "Отправьте команду help для получения списка комманд бота")
 
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.obj.text.lower() == "help" or event.obj.text.lower() == "помощь":
        vk.messages.send(peer_id = event.obj.peer_id, random_id = 0, message = "Список комманд:\n\ntest или тест\nТестовая проверка\n\nhelp или помощь\nСписок комманд\n\ntime или время\nВремя сервера\n\nserver или сервер\nКто запустил сервер\n\ninfo или инфо\nИнформация о боте")

    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.obj.text.lower() == "time" or event.obj.text.lower() == "время":
        vk.messages.send(peer_id = event.obj.peer_id, random_id = 0, message = "Время сервера: " + servertime)

    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.obj.text.lower() == "server" or event.obj.text.lower() == "сервер":
        vk.messages.send(peer_id = event.obj.peer_id, random_id = 0, message = "Сервер запустил: " + server)

    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.obj.text.lower() == "info" or event.obj.text.lower() == "инфо":
        vk.messages.send(peer_id = event.obj.peer_id, random_id = 0, message = "Версия: " + version + "\nVK API: " + api_version + "\nСистема: " + system + "\nЯзык: " + language + "\n\nРазработчик:")

time.sleep(longpool_sleep)
```

консоль выдает ошибку при запуске -
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и т.д..
извините за скриншот, но с текстом из консоли траблы

Comment: `longpoll for this group is not enabled` - предпоследняя строка. Зайдите в ваше сообщество -> управление -> работа с API -> Long Poll API -> [отключено] -> [включено] и перезапустите бота

Comment: @Стас, в консоли ошибок нету, но при вводе сообщения ( по типу хелп, тайм), бот никак не реагирует..

Comment: мне кажется, что токен необходимо было скрыть

Comment: @TheNick-Ник, токен скрыт был( большая его часть - обрезана)

Comment: @TheNick-Ник, все равно странно, что ошибок нету, а бот работать не хочет